# How to find a keyword in a class' properties' properties

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using intelliJ and I want to find a way to search the words that a class object and also in their properties have to check if I can use it to pull some information. I want to search if an object has some keyword in its public methods or variables so that I can confirm if this class has the information I need and I call pull it.

For example, let's say I want to find keyword 'language' and I got class `Person`.
Person has methods `getCountry()`, `getMother()`, `getEducation()`, etc.
`getCountry()` returns class `Country` and Country has `getLanguage()` and that's how I would find the method for language.

Is there way I can do this type of search?

I use Ctrl+F to find a keyword in the class but the scope pretty much ends there. I then need to search each object that class contains and then search on them for that keyword.